# NSProtocolChecker -- Still Implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Per Apple's docs, there should be a Foundation class [`NSProtocolChecker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProtocolChecker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSProtocolChecker) that inherits from `NSProxy`. With Xcode 7.0.1, I can use `NSProxy` in either Objective-C or Swift, but get an `Unknown type name` error when trying to use `NSProtocolChecker`. There are also no results when searching the documentation that ships with Xcode 7.0.1.

Has this class been removed?

Answer (score 1):

This is available for Mac projects, but not on iOS projects, the link in the initial docs was for the Mac version of the `Foundation` Library. The iOS version of the docs for [`NSProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003719) does not include `NSProtocolChecker`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 7. I can compile the following code correctly (in Swift). How are you instancing it?

```
var kk = NSProtocolChecker(target: self, `protocol`: StepInteractionProtocol.self)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in iOS or on a Mac?

Comment: I am doing this on a Mac

Comment: The question is about iOS.

Comment: my bad.. i missed the iOS tag.